# Consume simple web service on button click

Tags: c#, json, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a simple view with a button. When I click the button I would like to call the web service and use its data. This is my view :

page1.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     x:Class="HelloWorld.Pages.Page1"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Pages"
  <StackLayout Padding="20, 10" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <Button Clicked="B1_Clicked"
            Text="Click Me" />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

page1.xaml.cs

```
public page1(Models.Info info)
{
InitializeComponent();
}
private void B1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Service src = new Service();
     //how to use the data here
}
```

this is the service.cs

```
public async Task<Data> GetInfoAsync()
    { 
        DataInfo = null;
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            HttpContent content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://www.getdata/feed", content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataInfo>(json);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(data.data);
        return data.data;
    }
```

I guess its pretty simple but I'm new to xamarin so forgive my lack of knoledge :)

Comment: This sounds like you are asking "how do I call a webservice" to wich the anser is: "Wich kind of Webservice?"

Comment: @Christopher I added the service sorry :)

Comment: I have to warn you about your exception Handling. That code is very dangerous, as you will continue after a fatal Exception. Something you should never try to do. You should read those two articels on poper exception handling before you release something like that into Productive Code: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are already calling the service - you just need to call the GetInfoAsync method from your event handler

```
private async void B1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Service src = new Service();
     var data = await src.GetInfoAsync();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to call a web service is to use Refit.

This is plugin that simplifies the code you need to write to call a web service.

It also handles passing headers and deserialising from Json to a class.

[There are a lot of examples at its GitHub repo here](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit)

If you are just starting out I would recommend using a MVVM framework before you get too far down the road with code behind. [I use FreshMvvm](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm).

Comment: I already have the service. I don't know how to call it in the page1.xaml.cs and use it's data :/

Comment: Yes, Refit allows you to call that service. Examples on how to do that at the  link I provided.

Comment: It's a huge topic and depends on how the service was written and what the endpoints look like. Lots of different examples at the link.

Comment: I did not downvote it. I'm reading the link you provided about **Refit**